# What is the semicolon's role here?

Tags: sentence-construction, metaphors, semicolons

In this following context,  how does the semi-colon play? Should it not be colon (:) or emdash (—) here? And I thought the phrase ''a ceaseless heaving of waves up and down'' may be metaphor. So I want to know the reason why the author didn't give complete sentence using like ''just as'' or something like that before the metaphor phrase.

Explain this to me...

The context:

> These phenomena have merely momentary duration. They die every moment,
> and every moment new phenomena are born; a perpetual dying and coming
> to birth, **a ceaseless heaving of waves up and down**.

Source: Page.7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Other writers might use a dash in your cited context, which doesn't *quite* match the syntactic role normally assigned to the semicolon. It's often used to join two independent *clauses* - but in this case what we've got is two consecutive *noun phrases* following the "statement" ***new phenomena are born***. Those two noun phrases rephrase and restate preceding noun ***new phenomena***, but they're not explicitly linked to any verb (that's why I'd have used a dash, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with FumbleFingers. This is not quite the correct use of the semicolon.

It's not unheard of, though, to use it in this stylistic way to mark a larger pause. You just have to understand an ellipsis of "it is" after the semicolon to repair the defective clause.

A dash would have been more correct but would have seemed abrupt and inelegant given the content of the sentence. A colon would have been good, setting up an equivalence between the two halves.

Comment: Many style guides speak derisively about using semicolons as 'super-commas'.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak. Do you say to put colon instead of semicolon before two noun phrases? I'm not clear ''the two halves''.

Comment: ...new phenomena are born: (it is) a perpetual dying and coming to birth, a ceaseless heaving of waves up and down.??? @Luke Sawczak.

Comment: @SakyaKim If you keep the semicolon, there's an implied "it is". If you use a colon, it's fine. And the equivalence would be between the situation described in the half of the sentence before the colon, and the two noun phrases in the half after the colon.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I intend no endorsement of it either :)

Comment: @Luke Sawczak, I think last phrase is a metaphor, and how does the metaphor connect to its preceding phrase? Shouldn't it connect to it using 'just as' or something like that?  Or is  it a kind of writing style?

Comment: @SakyaKim The high school English answer (for what it's worth...) would be that "as" is a simile, and "is" is a metaphor. Either one would be fine.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak, Thanks for your suggestion. Do you say that is simile? So I think it should give an  explicit clause using simile tools 'as' or like' .

Comment: @SakyaKim It could have been written as a simile if desired. It doesn't have to be. The author wrote it as a metaphor, and that works equally well.